# DecimalField Converts Zero to 0E-10

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Django 1.6, Python 2.7.5+, PostgreSQL 9.1, Linux.

I have several decimal fields defined in the model like this:

```
min_inclusive = models.DecimalField(_('minimum inclusive'), max_digits=19,
                    decimal_places=10,
                    help_text=_("Enter the minimum (inclusive) value for this concept."),
                    null=True, blank=True)
```

Via the admin interface when I enter a `0` (zero)  and save the object I get `0E-10` as the value.

So, why doesn't it just store and display a zero?

The documentation doesn't specify if `decimal_places` is forced or if it is a maximum number.

Is this display because 10 places are **required**?  If so, the using the default form widget, `TextInput`, it seems to me that is should just expand to that size or at least scroll to that size.

In PostgreSQL it is stored as `0.0000000000`

Comment: The problem seems to be in the postgres backend or Psycopg 2.5.2 adapter... I have the same problem and the data in postgres is 0.00000000   but when fetched by django it comes up as Decimal("0E-8") (with shell access not only admin), if I switch to sqlite3 backend then it works perfectly

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have also ran into this problem and found out that actually everything is working right. In Python if you actually define something like this `Decimal("0.0000000000")` you will see this in the console:

```
>>> Decimal("0.0000000000")
Decimal('0E-10')
```

In my situation I was converting from *SQLite3* backend to *PostgreSQL* for production. Everything was working fine in SQLite, because it doesn't explicitly show (or store) all decimal digits. So if you insert `0` in an SQLite number field and then select it, you will get `0`.

But if you insert `0` in a *PostgreSQL* numeric field it will do a zero fill on the decimal and insert `0.0000000000`. So when Python puts this in a Decimal you will see `Decimal("0E-10")`.

**UPDATE - fixed in Django 1.8**

Comment: But to post the solution to the issue, just for completeness. 

Yes, Django does store the field contents as decimal.Decimal objects.  In your templates or if writing out to a file (as I need to do) you need to use the formatting option. 

Example using the previously used model field:

str('%.10g' % self.min_inclusive).strip()
  
This removes all non-significant zeros. So it gives me '0' for a zero.

Comment: ***TIP:*** In a template you can use `{{ value|floatformat }}` to get a sensible output for decimals.